# Replace multiple strings in text files with different texts

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a text file like so:

**template.txt**

```
hello my name is [MYNAME], and i am of age [AGE].
i live in [COUNTRY].
i love to eat [FOOD]
```

and I am trying to replace whatever is in the square brackets with strings from a list example

```
//         // name //country // age // food           
p.Add(new Person("jack", "NZ", "20", "Prawns"));
p.Add(new Person("ana", "AUS", "23", "Chicken"));
p.Add(new Person("tom", "USA", "30", "Lamb"));
p.Add(new Person("ken", "JAPAN", "15", "Candy"));
```

so far I have tried the below function which I call inside a loop

```
//loop
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int count = 0;
  foreach (var l in p)
  {
    FindAndReplace("template.txt","output"+count+".txt" ,"[MYNAME]",l.name);
    FindAndReplace("template.txt","output"+count+".txt" ,"[COUNTRY]",l.country);
    FindAndReplace("template.txt","output"+count+".txt" ,"[AGE]",l.age);
    FindAndReplace("template.txt","output"+count+".txt" ,"[FOOD]",l.food);
    count++;
  }
}
//find and replace function
 private static void FindAndReplace(string template_path,string save_path,string find,string replace)
        {           
            using (var sourceFile = File.OpenText(template_path))
            {
                // Open a stream for the temporary file
                using (var tempFileStream = new StreamWriter(save_path))
                {
                    string line;
                    // read lines while the file has them
                    while ((line = sourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // Do the word replacement
                        line = line.Replace(find, replace);
                        // Write the modified line to the new file
                        tempFileStream.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
  
        }
```

this is what I have done. But the output I get is this

**output1.txt**

```
hello my name is [MYNAME], and i am of age [AGE].
i live in [COUNTRY].
i love to eat Prawns
```

**output2.txt**

```
hello my name is [MYNAME], and i am of age [AGE].
i live in [COUNTRY].
i love to eat Chicken
```

Only the last text is replaced.

Comment: I suspect a typo. The code you have put in this page has several typos and would not compile (forech isn't a keyword, and your while loop doesn't have matching parens), so its going to be hard or impossible for someone to find the actual typo in the code that you did not include...

Comment: For the same value of count you open the template file, replace a string and write to the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of a function try doing something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
               int count = 0;
                foreach (var l in p)
                {                  
                    using (var sourceFile = File.OpenText("template.txt"))
                    {
                        // Open a stream for the temporary file
                        using (var tempFileStream = new StreamWriter("output" + count + ".txt"))
                        {
                            string line;
                            // read lines while the file has them
                            while ((line = sourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                               
                                line = line.Replace("[MYNAME]", l.name);
                                line = line.Replace("[COUNTRY]", l.country);
                                line = line.Replace("[AGE]", l.age);
                                line = line.Replace("[FOOD]", l.food);
                                tempFileStream.WriteLine(line);
                            }// end of while loop
                        }
                      count++;
                    }//end foreach loop                             
                }
            }//end of main
```

Answer (score 5):

Every time you call `FindAndReplace` you are overwriting the last file written.

When you call it the first time it reads the template file, replaces a specific placeholder (`[MYNAME]`) with a value and writes it to a new file.
In the next call you take the template again so `[MYNAME]` is not replaced anymore and only replaces the country and writes it to the same file overwriting the content. This repeats till you get to the last call.

That is why only `[FOOD]` is replaced.
Try replacing all the text in one go and then writing it to the file.